# UIPageControl + circular (Infinite) scrolling

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I am working on app in which i have to make welcome screen. In that `UIPageControl` i need to display different 9 subviews. Also need infinite circular scrolling in that. It means after page-9 if i slide than page-1 should appear.

I have tried so much to implement it but never got expected results.

Can anyone help me out to get the best solution for it.

Thanks.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268456/how-can-i-make-uiscrollview-infinite-in-ios
or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430267/uiscrollview-infinite-scrolling

Comment: Can i know who & why down voted this question ? Please whoever down voted if you have guts than place the reason for down vote.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommended to use [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) for doing this task. I do following changes in to there demo **Buttons Demo**

**.h class**

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL wrap;
```

**.m class**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _wrap = YES;
    //configure carousel
    carousel.type = iCarouselTypeLinear;
}

- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{

    return 9;
}


- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UILabel *label = nil;

    //create new view if no view is available for recycling
    if (view == nil)
    {
        view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200.0f, 400)];
        view.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
        ((UIImageView *)view).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"page.png"];
        view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:view.bounds];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        label.font = [label.font fontWithSize:50];
        label.tag = 1;
        [view addSubview:label];
    }
    else
    {
        //get a reference to the label in the recycled view
        label = (UILabel *)[view viewWithTag:1];
    }

       label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", index];

    return view;
}


- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel placeholderViewAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UILabel *label = nil;

    //create new view if no view is available for recycling
    if (view == nil)
    {
        //don't do anything specific to the index within
        //this `if (view == nil) {...}` statement because the view will be
        //recycled and used with other index values later
        view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200.0f, 400.0f)];
        view.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];

        ((UIImageView *)view).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"page.png"];
        view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;

        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:view.bounds];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        label.font = [label.font fontWithSize:50.0f];
        label.tag = 1;
        [view addSubview:label];
    }
    else
    {
        //get a reference to the label in the recycled view
        label = (UILabel *)[view viewWithTag:1];
    }

        label.text = (index == 0)? @"[": @"]";

    return view;
}


- (CGFloat)carousel:(iCarousel *)_carousel valueForOption:(iCarouselOption)option withDefault:(CGFloat)value
{
    //customize carousel display
    switch (option)
    {
        case iCarouselOptionWrap:
        {
            //normally you would hard-code this to YES or NO
            return _wrap;
        }
        case iCarouselOptionSpacing:
        {
            //add a bit of spacing between the item views
            return value * 1.05f;
        }
        case iCarouselOptionFadeMax:
        {
            if (carousel.type == iCarouselTypeCustom)
            {
                //set opacity based on distance from camera
                return 0.0f;
            }
            return value;
        }
        default:
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
- (CATransform3D)carousel:(iCarousel *)_carousel itemTransformForOffset:(CGFloat)offset baseTransform:(CATransform3D)transform
{
    //implement 'flip3D' style carousel
    transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, M_PI / 8.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    return CATransform3DTranslate(transform, 0.0f, 0.0f, offset * carousel.itemWidth);
}
```

or getting tapped Button index:-

```
- (void)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel didSelectItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    NSLog(@"Tapped view number: %d", index);
}
```

**it's Output is :-**

[image]

[Here is Attached Demo](http://ge.tt/4zq0M7S1/v/0)