# How can I make UIScrollView/UIPageControl infinite?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiscrollview

I have created a simple image scrolling with `UIPageControl` and `UIScrollView`, I have three pages ! so what I need is when user scrolls `page 0` to left , actually scroll should move  to the `page 3` and vice versa . I have checked Apple sample code but it was so complicated !, here is my codes :

```
- (void)setupScrollView {


    _pageControl.currentPage = 0;
    _pageControl.numberOfPages = 3;
    [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(_scrollView.frame.size.width * _pageControl.numberOfPages, _scrollView.frame.size.height)];
    _scrollView.delegate = self;

    [self createPageWithImage:_image1 forPage:0];
    [self createPageWithImage:_image2 forPage:1];
    [self createPageWithImage:_image3 forPage:2];


}

    - (void)createPageWithImage:(UIImageView *)frameImage forPage:(int)page
    {
        UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(_scrollView.frame.size.width * page, 0, _scrollView.frame.size.width, _scrollView.frame.size.height)];
        [newView addSubview: frameImage];
        [_scrollView addSubview: newView];

    }


    - (void)scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView *) sView
    {

        CGFloat offset = _scrollView.contentOffset.x;
        CGFloat pageSize = _scrollView.frame.size.width;

        int page = floor((offset + (pageSize/2)) / pageSize);
        _pageControl.currentPage = page;



    }





- (IBAction)changeThePage
{

    CGRect pageRect = CGRectMake(_pageControl.currentPage * _scrollView.frame.size.width, 0, _scrollView.frame.size.width, _scrollView.frame.size.height);

    [_scrollView scrollRectToVisible: pageRect animated: YES];
}
```

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22525594/uipagecontrol-circular-infinite-scrolling/22526183#22526183

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the methods which I have changed. I have commented wherever necessary.

```
- (void)setupScrollView {
    _pageControl.currentPage = 0;
    _pageControl.numberOfPages = 3 ;
    //Add 2 more pages.
    [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(_scrollView.frame.size.width * (_pageControl.numberOfPages + 2), _scrollView.frame.size.height)];
    _scrollView.delegate = self;

    // Seriously recommend this for this type of apps.
    _scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

    // Do not instantiate imageviews. Send only image names as string.
    // Add last image at beginning of scroll view.
    [self createPageWithImageName:@"imageName3" forPage:0];

    // Increase page number of existing images.
    [self createPageWithImageName:@"imageName1" forPage:1];
    [self createPageWithImageName:@"imageName2" forPage:2];
    [self createPageWithImageName:@"imageName3" forPage:3];

    //Add first image at end of scroll view
    [self createPageWithImageName:@"imageName1" forPage:4];

    // Show first image but present in second page.
    [_scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(_scrollView.frame.size.width, 0) animated:NO];
}

// Instead of sending image views, send image name. Create image view inside this method.
// This is because, since we are adding two more images, separate image view needs
// to be created. Otherwise, same image view will be used and one added at the end 
// will be used as the frame of the image.
- (void)createPageWithImageName:(NSString *)imageName forPage:(int)page
{

    UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(_scrollView.frame.size.width * page, 0, _scrollView.frame.size.width, _scrollView.frame.size.height)];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:newView.bounds];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

    [newView addSubview: imageView];
    [_scrollView addSubview: newView];

}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView *) sView
{
    CGFloat offset = _scrollView.contentOffset.x;
    CGFloat pageSize = _scrollView.frame.size.width;

    int page = floor((offset + (pageSize/2)) / pageSize);
    if (page == 0) {
        page = _pageControl.numberOfPages - 1;
    }
    else if (page == _pageControl.numberOfPages + 1) {
        page = 0;
    }
    else {
        page = page - 1;
    }
    _pageControl.currentPage = page;

    // If present in scroll view's first page, move it to second last page
    if (offset < pageSize) {
        [_scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(pageSize * 3 + offset, 0) animated:NO];
    }
    // If present in scroll view's last page, move it to second page.
    else if (offset >= pageSize * (_pageControl.numberOfPages + 1)) {
        CGFloat difference = offset - pageSize * _pageControl.numberOfPages;
        [_scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(difference, 0) animated:NO];
    }
}
```

The method of `changeThePage` is not needed for this code.

Hope this answer helps you.

Comment: Is it happening only in page 0? I am not sure what is it. Just try this once. Inside the method of `- (void)createPageWithImage:(UIImageView *)frameImage forPage:(int)page`, just add this line and see. `[frameImage setFrame:newView.bounds];`

Comment: It is not happening for me. Some other part of your code is causing that problem. Debug once. Specifically parts of code where you are using scroll view.

Comment: Sure. You can send me.

Comment: Are you sure you have sent me correct link? Because in this link, I can see only one panoramic image. And also, I can't see any of your previous code?

Comment: Sorry. Found the mistake. I was adding the same image view again. Hence, it was vanishing in the first place. When I did it, I was creating image views inside the parameters, and hence I didn't face the problem. But silly me that I didn't look into this problem. Presently, I have edited the code and it is working.

Comment: Brilliant ! thanks !! but I actually I have to mentioned UIImageView not image name , because images will be downloaded from server , it's not local ! I will look into it , thanks again

Comment: Yup. No problem. It is my duty that if I give answer, I do have to give it correctly. Regarding images, you can download it from server and then pass it as parameter instead of image view or else, you can create separate image view for them and then send it. Anyways, it was nice helping you. :)

Comment: Sorry for keep bothering ! can I have your email , I faced with a tiny problem here ?

Comment: I don't check my mail so frequently. Why don't you post it as separate question? Besides you will get quick answers if you post it here.

Comment: Thanks check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25590345/having-issue-with-infinite-uiscrollview-uipagecontrol-infinite-scrolling